# Nested Query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables:

### Table 1: tbluser

**ID**    **Name** 
1 ..........    name1 
2  ..........   name2 
3   ..........  name3

Another table that links tbluser and tblrole

Table2: tbllinkuserrole 
**userid**..........**roleid** 
1 ............2
1 ..........    2
1 ..........    2
2  ..........   2
3  ..........   1

I would like to fetch the tbluser.Name and the user role from tbllinkuserrole in to a table: a single table row(user record) can have multiple rows inside the column 'role' based on the roles fetched from tbllinkuser role. A user can have multiple roles. 
can you help me out...

Comment: Which Laravel version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel have Models (Eloquent), in the model class are some functions that are easy to user to fetch data from table. (this works with Laravel 5.2)

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

So first of all, you need a User model (`php artisan make:model User`). You need to link the User modal to the right table.

```
//File: /laravel/app/User.php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'tbluser';

    public function userRoles() {
        //Get the table data with the user roles
        $this->hasMany('App\UserRoles', 'user_id', 'id');
        //First argument gets the UserRoles Modal
        //Second argument get the UserRoles column 'user_id'
        //Third argument get the User table - column id
}

//File: /laravel/app/UserRoles.php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class UserRoles extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbllinkuserrole';

    public function rank() {
        //Get the table data with role
        $this->hasOne('App\Roles', 'id', 'role_id');
        //First argument gets the Roles Modal (table)
        //Second argument get the Roles column 'id'
        //Third argument get the UserRoles modal (table) - column role_id
}

//File: /laravel/app/Roles.php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Roles extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblroles';
}
```

Now if you call `Auth::user()->userRoles` you will get an array with all rows from table that are linked to the current user.

And when you're running this you dump all the user rank data.

```
foreach(Auth::user()->userRoles as $userrole) {
    {{ dump($userrole) }}
    {{ dump($userrole->rank) }}
}
```

I hope this works for you!

More information can be found on https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS ONE

```
SELECT tbllinkuserrole.userid, tbllinkuserrole.roleid, tbluser.name
FROM tbllinkuserrole, tbluser
WHERE tbllinkuserrole.userid = tbluser.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysql to get the row values as column,

```
SELECT U.id, U.Name, MAX(CASE WHEN R.roleid = 1 THEN R.roleid END) role_1, MAX(CASE WHEN R.roleid = 2 THEN R.roleid END) role_2 from table_c AS U LEFT JOIN table_b AS R on (U.id = R.userid) WHERE 1 GROUP BY U.id
```

Comment: how to display in the table for a single user row, create multiple rows inside the column "Role". because a user can have multiple roles..i want to display all the roles inside one row under column Role.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you wanted each of your role ids in each column